# Why does the following Jquery event.target does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my code in question

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  var button = $('#open_button');
  var box = $('#dropdown');

  function init() {
    eventsInit();
  }

  function eventsInit() {
    box.hide();
    button.on('click', open);
  }

  function open(event) {
    if (event.target !== button[0]) {
      box.hide();
    } else {
      box.show();
    }
  }

  init();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

#dropdown {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <form action="" id="open_button">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the text" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="dropdown"></div>
```

I need to dropdown when I click on the input form input element and close it when I click outside.

My code I believe it says, if the click target is not the button, close the dropdown, else show.

Could someone explain, why doesnt it work ?

Comment: change button[0]  to button

Comment: @tech2017 No. The [0] accesses the underlying DOM object -- that's correct because `event.target` is also a DOM element.

Comment: but why var button = $('#open_button'); ?

Comment: Note that you've put your jQuery code in an IIFE, not a document.ready event handler. Depending on where you've placed that script, the DOM may not be ready before you attempt to use it

Comment: is the target actually the element? My guess it is a child. console.log(event.target)

Comment: simply check for ids then `event.target.id` to your button id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(event.target !== button[0])` is always true.

- `event.target` is the `<input>` field.
- `button[0]` is the `<form>` element.

You could move the #open_button id to the input field, that would cause the box to appear when the user clicks the input field -- but then the box would never disappear (because your `if` condition would never return true.)

What you really want are `focus` and `blur` handlers on the input field, to show and hide the box respectively:

```js
$('#open_button input').on('focus', function() {
  $('#dropdown').show()
}).on('blur', function() {
  $('#dropdown').hide()
});

// added to answer per comment below:
$('#dropdown').on('mousedown',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // prevent input field from losing focus when user clicks inside the box
});

$('#dropdown').hide();
```

```css
#dropdown {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <form action="" id="open_button">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the text" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="dropdown"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the comment. It indeed works, however, did you observe that, the box closes even when it is clicked inside the box. Could you please suggest a way not to close the box when it is clicked inside the box.

Comment: In my snippet the box appears when you click in the input field, and disappears when you click outside the input field.  Is that not what you want it to do?

Comment: Oh, wait, I get it. 1 sec.

Comment: @jeff OK, I've added that to the answer.

Comment: From a functional point of view it works the way it should. However, for my learning could you please put the code in such as way that, it checks if, the event.target === id && event.target === dropdown. If it is true, dropdown remains open or opens. Else it closes.

Comment: That wouldn't really work, because the event target is always the same; you can't use that as the condition for two opposite behaviors.